# what is the problem with below selection sort algorithm

Tags: c, selection-sort

```
void main()
{
    int a[] = { 10, 3, 4, 2, 1, 0 };
    int i = 0;
    int temp_index;
    int temp_min;
    int temp;
    a[i];
    int j;
    a[j];
    int n = sizeof(a) / sizeof(int);
    for (; i < n - 1; i++)
    {
        int temp_min = i;
        int j = i + 1;
        for (; j < n; j++)
        {
            if (a[i] > a[j])
            {
                temp_min = j;
            }
        }

        int temp = a[temp_min];
        a[temp_min] = a[i];
        a[i] = temp;
    }

    int k = 0;

    for (; k < n; k++)
    {
        printf("%d", a[k]);
    }
}
```

Comment: expected output :0 1 2 3 4 10

Comment: Actual Output?   Also, ***use a debugger***.  Set a breakpoint at the beginning, and step through each line of code.

Comment: What differences do you see if you compare to other implementations?

Comment: What is `a[j];` expected to do? `j` is uninitialized and you access some "random" element of the array. Also there is no point in reading the value if you don't use it.

Comment: nit-pick: the `sizeof` macro yields a value of type `size_t`, not `int`

Comment: `void main` is invalid C.

Answer (score 1):

you compare

```
if (a[i] > a[j]) {
    temp_min = j;
}
```

instead of 
`if (a[temp_min] > a[j]) { ... }`

Comment: thank you somuch would you please expalin me the reason of that

Answer (score -1):

Selection sort selects the smallest number from a[i].. a[n-1] to the ith position.For achieving this you can change your for loop--

```
for (; i < n - 1; i++)
{
    int temp_min = a[i];
    int swapIndex=-1;
    int j = i + 1;
    for (; j < n; j++)
    {
        if (temp_min > a[j])
        {
            temp_min = a[j];
            swapIndex = j;
        }
    }
    if(swapIndex !=-1){
    a[swapIndex] = a[i];
    a[i] = temp_min;
    }

}
```

Also you can change the

```
 if (a[i] > a[j])
 {
            temp_min = j;
 }
```

part in your code to this -

```
if (a[temp_min] > a[j])
 {
     temp_min = j;
 }
```

it will work but in that case --

```
int temp = a[temp_min];
a[temp_min] = a[i];
a[i] = temp;
```

This swap part will be redundant for an already sorted array like {1,2,3,4}

Comment: Edited with explanation